# Probability Lottery Question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In the Maryland Lotto game to win the grand prize the contestant must match six distinct numbers 1 through 49 randomly drawn by a lottery representative. What is the probability of choosing the winning numbers?

It would be (49 P 6) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the order of drawing the numbers does not matter.

Comment: Ah i thought order mattered.  So (49 C 6)?

Comment: That is right.  Your entry card does not specify an order, they just check the list of numbers on the card against the list of numbers drawn.

Answer (score 0):

There is one favourable outcome out of $\binom{49}{6}$ outcomes. Hence the probability is
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{49}{6}}.
$$